# Google classroom API - creating a course with Active status and using service account errors out

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-classroom

I am using googleapis to create a classroom course with a service account.
Everything works well if I don't specify the status and the course is created with status: PROVISIONED.

However, if I try to update the status to ACTIVE or create a course with status ACTIVE I get an error:
GaxiosError: @CourseStateDenied This user cannot create or transition courses into the requested state.

Here's some relevant code:

```
// authenticate with service account
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
keyFile: path.join(__dirname, 'service_account_creds.json'),
scopes: [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos'
],
});

const authClient = await auth.getClient();
google.options({auth: authClient});

// create a course with status: ACTIVE
const res = await classroom.courses.create({
  requestBody: {
    name: 'Test Course',
    description: 'this is my course description',
    ownerId: 'me',
    courseState: 'ACTIVE'
  }
});
console.log(res.data);
```

Comment: How do you create `authClient`? Does the service account impersonate you or act on his own behalf? And how dou you create `classroom`?

Comment: Also, which kind of Google Workspace account do you have?

Comment: How did you grant the service account access to your workspace?  Is your workspace still in trial status?

Answer (score 0):

### I think the problem is related to your account

See the documentation for [creating courses](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-courses#create_a_course):

> Courses are created with the courseState set to PROVISIONED by default; however, this can be overridden to ACTIVE. If the course is created in the PROVISIONED state, the teacher identified in the ownerId must accept the class in the Classroom UI or the course must be updated through the API to change the courseState to ACTIVE and make it available to their students.

And then:

> Note: Consumer accounts (*@gmail.com) cannot create courses in ACTIVE state. Requests to do so will return 403: PERMISSION_DENIED.

**In other words, consumer accounts are not allowed to create courses with the status `ACTIVE`.**

Answer (score 0):

ziganotschka got it almost on the spot. The missing details is that you are using a service account without impersonation, so the course is being created with the service account as the owner.

If you are doing it for a school/university, you need to grant the service account domain-wide access to create courses for the users. Then:

1. If the school/uni wants to allow teachers to create their own classes, you can set the credentials `subject` the user that will be the main teacher.
2. Regardless of whether the teachers are allowed to create new classes, you can set the credentials `subject` to an Admin email, allowing you to create courses for other users.